# Font not seems in hosting like local

Tags: css, cross-browser, font-face

I want to use the font named **Rexlia**. CSS code is so:

```
@font-face
{
    font-family: "Rexlia";
    src: url('rexliarg.ttf');
}
```

.ttf and css file are in same folder. In local font works, but I deploy site to hosting, font-family is Rexlia, but font does not seems like in local. Font lose its design. Is there any way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your src path is relative to the website , not the CSS document. If the published path has the CSS in a subfolder, it will not resolve. Try an absolute path with your published version to quickly rule that out.